# When i write npm i.Is installing only package-lock.json

Tags: node.js, npm-install, npm-package

I have a problem with starting node, I type npm i and it pops up

```
asl Err! code ENOENT
asl Err! syscall open
asl Err! path C:\Users\adria\Desktop\app/package.json
asl Err! errno -4058
asl Err! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\adria\Desktop\app\package.json'
asl Err! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
asl Err! enoent

asl Err! A complete log of this run can be found in:
asl Err! C:\Users\adria\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-04T19_10_31_667Z-debug-0.log
```

Then the package-lock.json file with such content is installed

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "lockfileVersion": 3,
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {}
}
```

I tried:

1. change in -g files to --location=global
2. adding a new path to the environment variables of the system, where I have node, i.e. C:\Program Files\nodejs
3. I installed node: 14 | 16 | 18 | 20 and the versions of npm they support
4. I tried formatting the computer also did not help
5. I saved the node installation location on the desktop
6. I also tried other options but there were so many that I don't remember all of them

The solution may be simple, but it's too hard for me.

Comment: `no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\adria\Desktop\app\package.json'` If there's no package.json what are you trying to install?

Comment: Is your package-lock.json really located at Desktop/app/package.json ?

Comment: So how I can fix it?@Clive